# problem im motion control with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i have a problem in motion control in matlab
imagine a four bar linkage mechanism like this.as you you know in an ordinary 4 bar linkage we have 2 fix points but here we have just one & the second one it fixed to a pinion (small gear).we have the ratio of gears so we have a relation between teta1 & teta2
teta2 = 5*teta1    (the mechanism can rotate in the first fix point)

i used to write this code for motion control but the when i run it the graphs are not correct (because they should be something linke sin or cos graph)

d(n) is a auxiliry vector for solving equations
please ask if you have further questions

this is the code :

```
clc,
close all,
clear all,

ax=0;

ay=0;

r1=12;

r2=7;

r3=9;

r4=5;



n=0;

for teta1=0:pi/180:2*pi

    n=n+1;

D = r1*exp(i*teta1)-r2*exp(i*5*teta1);

tetad(n) = angle(D);

d(n) = abs(D);

landa(n)=acos((d(n)^2+(r3)^2-(r4)^2)/(2*d(n)*r3));

alfa(n)=acos((d(n)^2+(r4)^2-(r3)^2)/(2*d(n)*r4));

teta3(n)=landa(n)+tetad(n);

teta4(n)=(+pi-alfa(n)+tetad(n));

end



aa(n)=teta1*180/pi;

hh(n)=tetad(n)*180/pi;

bb(n)=landa(n)*180/pi;

cc(n)=alfa(n)*180/pi;

nn(n)=teta3(n)*180/pi;

dd(n)=5*teta1*180/pi;

ee(n)=teta4(n)*180/pi;


figure(1),plot(aa,hh),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('tetad');

figure(2),plot(aa,d),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('d');

figure(3),plot(aa,bb),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('landa');

figure(4),plot(aa,cc),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('alfa');

figure(5),plot(aa,nn),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('teta3');

figure(6),plot(aa,dd),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('5*teta1');

figure(7),plot(aa,ee),xlabel('teta1'),ylabel('teta4');
```

Comment: Please format your code as code -- if you don't know how to do this read the FAQ.  And please only post the minimum required to state your problem -- but no less than that.  There are a lot of SOers who are tolerant of all sorts of crazy formatting, but there are a lot who aren't and won't bother trying to help you unless you make it easier for us.  And then there's the odd curmudgeon like me who will take time to point out the errors of your ways but not spend that time deciphering your question.  It's a funny old world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to solve here, but probably you want to move the `end` of your for-loop a few lines down, so the vectors you plot contain all values and not only the last one.

Comment: one more problem is this error can you solve this :

Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
> In dynamic3 at 40
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
> In dynamic3 at 41
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
> In dynamic3 at 42
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
> In dynamic3 at 44
>>

Comment: If you want somebody to help you, I strongly suggest you put more effort into formatting your questions properly. From "dynamic3 at 41" I can only guess what line this relates to. Your `alfa` is complex, so plotting it creates a warning.

Comment: Btw. the greek letters are called theta, alpha and lambda!